# SwiftUI context menu not passing correct variable

Tags: contextmenu, swiftui

I would expect that sheet that is presented show the actual string that was pressed in the list.

**i.e, long press G and the presenting sheet should show G**

Unfortunately it doesn't, I'm assuming this is a SwiftUI bug.

Does anyone have a clean solution for this?

Thanks

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    @State var showing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).font(.largeTitle)
                        .contextMenu {
                            self.contextEdit(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func contextEdit(_ item: String) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showing.toggle()
            print(item)
        }) {
            Text("Edit")
            Image(systemName: "circle")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showing) {
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds for me like an Apple Bug... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sheets` should only be used on the top level. This causes unexpected behaviour as the warnings in your output should also say.

Here is a working example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    @State var showing = false
    @State var currentItem: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).font(.largeTitle)
                        .contextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.currentItem = item
                            self.showing.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Edit")
                            Image(systemName: "circle")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showing) {
            Text(self.currentItem)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Greetings krjw

Comment: I have multiple sheets for my view - that's why I was attaching the sheet to the buttons.If I attach the sheet to the buttons, in your example it still works. I guess for the moment I'll have to live with my the massive nested ForEach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trail and error I found that his works well for my needs

```
struct PresentingContextItem<Destination: View>: View {

    @State private var showingDestination: Bool = false
    var destination: () -> Destination
    let title: String
    let image: String

    init(title: String, image: String, @ViewBuilder _ destination: @escaping () -> Destination) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingDestination.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(self.title)
            Image(systemName: self.image)
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDestination) {
            self.destination()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item).font(.largeTitle)
                    .contextMenu {
                        // option 1
                        PresentingContextItem(title: "Create", image: "circle") {
                            Text("Edit...\(item)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                        // option 2
                        self.starItem(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func starItem(_ item: String) -> some View {
        PresentingContextItem(title: "Star", image: "star") {
            Text("Star...\(item)").foregroundColor(.green)
        }
    }
}
```